# Why Azure recommend not to deploy azure application gateway in hub network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway

As a [best practice of Azure Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/traditional-azure-networking-topology):

```
Don't deploy Layer-7 inbound NVAs, such as Azure Application Gateway, as a shared service in the central-hub virtual network. Instead, deploy them together with the application in their respective landing zones.
```

I wonder the reasons behind.

Deploying inbound NVAs in a hub(shares service VNET) may help in that:

- This VNET can be managed by an experienced Azure administrator, rather than users. If users misconfigure NVAs, administrators can use NSG to stop traffic (Defense in Depth).
- Network Administrator can add another NVAs between NVAs and backend applications, e.g., traffic inspection or audit.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the regional Azure Application Gateway provides a customizable layer 7 load-balancing solution. From the [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#configuration), Application Gateway is always deployed in a virtual network subnet. It should be deployed close to the application service region to reduce latency. If not, we need to set up the VPN connection or virtual network peering to connect the backend cross-region service when using the IP address or hostname. This also adds complex networking infrastructures and is not often flexible to troubleshoot.

Also, there are [constraints for peered virtual networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview#constraints-for-peered-virtual-networks). Some services (`Application Gateway (v1) SKU`) that use a Basic load balancer don't work over global virtual network peering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We can deploy shared service VNET (hub) and application VNET (spoke) in the same region to avoid cross region problems as you said.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is not about region. It's about why to deploy AGW and backend application in the same VNET.

Comment: AGW is always deployed into a VNet but the backend application is optionally deployed into a VNet. For example, you can select an app service as the backend.

Comment: That article just mentioned that it is not recommended to do that, but actually, you can implement an ingress DMZ behind an internet-facing load balancer(AGW). See this [high availability architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/dmz/nva-ha?tabs=cli#ingress-with-layer-7-nvas). Also, I think, avoiding adding AGW as a shared service in a network may reduce the chance that once the AGW frontend is broken, all traffic will be impacted.